# Property 'X' does not exist on type 'context | null'. ts(2339)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I can't figure this out. Why is TypeScript showing this error even though I have defined the type of the function in the type TasksContextType...

**Error:**
Property 'addTask' does not exist on type 'TaskContextType | null'. ts(2339)

**Component file using the addTask function:**

```
const { addTask } = useTasks();
```

**addTask function:**

```
const addTask = async (title: string) => {
    const taskRef = await addDoc(tasksCollection, {
      title,
      desc: "",
      completed: false,
    });
  };
```

**Type declaration:**

```
export type TaskContextType = {
  tasks: ITask[];
  addTask: (title: string) => Promise<void>;
};
```

**The TasksContext itself:**

```
const TasksCtx = createContext<TaskContextType | null>(null);
```

EDIT: **useTasks(); Hook:**

```
export const useTasks = () => useContext(TasksCtx);
```

Comment: Could you show the definition of the useTasks() hook? I think I know what the problem is, but I need to take a look at the definition of useTasks() to confirm my hypothesis.

Comment: As expected, it's exactly what @Yuji 'Tomita' Tomita has just answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const TasksCtx = createContext<TaskContextType | null>(null);`

Your default value is null, and its type is possibly null, so you would need to narrow down the type first.

```
const context = useContext(...)
if (context !== null) {
   context.addTask
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was to let the `createContext()` without param

```
const TasksCtx = createContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding a nullchecker.
context?.addTask

Answer (score 0):

In the context file:

```
import { createContext } from "react";

interface TaskContextType {
  tasks: ITask[];
  addTask: (title: string) => Promise<void>;
}

const TasksCtx = createContext< TaskContextType | null>(null);

export default TasksCtx;
```

then to use the context:

```
import {useContext} from "react";
import TasksCtx from "../context/TasksCtx";
const context = useContext(TasksCtx);
context?.addTask('string');
```